# this.my_object.filter is not a function

Tags: vue.js

Here is the template (for simplicity I added only one button):

```
<button v-on:click="test()">Test</button>
```

The script:

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: function() {
    return {
      boss_type: {
        prisoner: 'Some value',
        guardian: 'Some value',
        recidivist: 'Some value',
        moscow: 'Some value',
        secret: 'Some value',
        hospital: 'Some value'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    test: function() {
        this.boss_type.filter((type) => {
          console.log(type);
        });
    }
  }
...
```

On click the error occurs: `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.boss_type.filter is not a function"`

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

[`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a method of Array and `boss_type` is Object here. You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which returns an Array from an Object input:

```
test: function() {
    Object.keys(this.boss_type).filter(key => {
      console.log("key: ", key);
      console.log("value: ", this.boss_type[key]);
    });
}
```